# Userform switches date values

Tags: excel, vba

I made a userform which activates when a button is pressed. When the userform starts it retrieves cell values from a sheet. In the userform there is a button to save the values and overwrite the old one.

The cell values are dates. And that's where the problem begins. Somehow Excel does not know what date to put in the cell because each time I hit the save button it switches the day and the month value.

How can I tell VBA that it must be the format like this: dd-mm-yyyy?

**This is the code I use to retrieve the data from the cells:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

B1.Value = Sheets("DATAX").Range("N2")
E1.Value = Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2")

End Sub
```

**This is the code I use to place the data back in the cells:**

```
Private Sub SaveFileData_Click()

Sheets("DATAX").Range("N2") = B1.Value
Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2") = E1.Value

Unload Me
End Sub
```

**I tried (without success) to format the cell after of before placing the value like this:**

```
Private Sub SaveFileData_Click()

Sheets("DATAX").Range("N2").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
Sheets("DATAX").Range("N2") = B1.Value

Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2") = E1.Value

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: What `B1` is? Is it a control? If yes, what type of control?

Comment: @FaneDuru I think `B1` is  `Date Picker Calendar` control

Comment: @Mo Khalefa: Whouldn't it be wired to pass a date from the sheet to such a control?

Comment: @FaneDuru it is a textbox in the userform

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer what `B1`, `E1` are... Supposing that they are controls, usually keeping strings, it is important to be loaded with the date format as you need. Try this way, please:

```
B1.Value = Format(Sheets("DATAX").Range("N2").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
E1.Value = Format(Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Then proceed as you tried and see how the code behaves in this circumstances...

In order to trick the date format, without looking for the reason, please copy the next piece of code before pasting the date back:

```
Dim strArr As Variant, fixDate As Date
 strArr = Split(B1.Value, "-")
 fixDate = DateSerial(strArr(2), strArr(1), strArr(0))
 Debug.Print B1.Value, fixDate, Date 'what does it return here (3 dates)?
 Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
 Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2") = Format(fixDate, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

How does it behave now?

Comment: i tried what you suggested but no luck it still switches the month and day around each time when I overwrite it

Comment: @Jelle van der Heijden: OK. Let us try to see what is your default date format. Please try: `Debug.print Date`. What does it return in Immediate Window? I mean today date, but in what format...

Comment: i dont get the immediate window to pop up. But I did it via msgbox and the result is 15-6-2020.

Comment: Let us try a trick. I will adapt the above answer, since it may need some more code lines...

Comment: Maybe you need to convert `B1.Value` to Date then format it `Sheets("DATAX").Range("N2") = Format$(CDate(B1.Value), "dd-mm-yyyy")`

Comment: @Mo Khalefa: Excel makes an automate conversion, anyhow. But, from unknown reason, it does the conversion in a wrong way... Now I am trying to manipulate the string date in a way to reverse the day with month... If it will  not work as expected, I will try the same way, but this time without reversing the month with day.  Only creating an appropriate date using `DateSerial`...

Comment: @Jelle van der Heijden: No any news? I am taking it like a challenge... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru I will go and try it now. When I have news ill come back

Comment: @FaneDuru i tried your piece of code as you mentioned above. But it still switches the day and month. Even if I change it around as you suggested.

Comment: @FaneDuru Maybe its good to mention when the dates are being switched. So it it happens as following: I press the button, the userform gets opened. When initializing the userform it retreves the dates from cells. After this I can change the dates manually in the userform. Then there is a button which saves the dates back to the cells. So the first time I go trough the process the date is 1-3-2020. The second time this changes to 3-1-2020. It only happens when the day is lower then 12.

Comment: @Jelle van der Heijden: If I understood well, the date format after loading in the text box is shown correctly. Is it true? Independent of the month number... If yes, it is a very strange situation, if you also tried the way of the bottom of my answer code. Now I deleted it and adapted the code only for this case. When Excel pastes a string looking like a date, it guesses the date format. But, if we deliver it a real date, stating its 'composition' in terms of day, month, year, I cannot understand what is happening. Please try using again the updated code and let me know how it behaves...

Comment: @Jelle van der Heijden: And post, please what exactly `Debug.Print` returns. And confirm, please that the date shows normal in the text box...

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more testing and research I found a solution.

So instead of just taking the values I now declare them as dates so the code is as following:

**This is the code I use to retrieve the data from the cells:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ImportB1 As Date
ImportB1 = Sheets("DATAX").Range("N2").Value
B1 = ImportB1

Dim ImportE1 As Date
ImportE1 = Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2").Value
E1 = ImportE1

End Sub
```

**This is the code I use to place the data back in the cells:**

```
Private Sub SaveFileData_Click()

Dim DateB1 As Date
DateB1 = B1.Value
Sheets("DATAX").Range("N2") = DateB1

Dim DateE1 As Date
DateE1 = E1.Value
Sheets("DATAX").Range("O2") = DateE1

Unload Me
End Sub
```